# Flutter: RichText not working as expected

Tags: android, flutter, dart, richtext

I'm new to Flutter and trying to clone an app to learn it. I create an intro look like this in real app: [introduction screen in real app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOp9c.png)

And I use `RichText` to create that text but somehow it shows the code on the screen: [introduction screen in my clone app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UrS2.png)

Here is the code:

```
class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  const Body({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  int currentPage = 0;
  final List<Map<String, Object>> _introductionData = [
    {
      "image": "assets/images/intro_1.png",
      "title": "",
      "text": RichText(
        text: const TextSpan(
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          children: [
            TextSpan(
              text: 'Sign in first time ',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            TextSpan(text: 'success to get '),
            TextSpan(
              text: '50% off coupon ',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            TextSpan(text: 'and '),
            TextSpan(
              text: 'lottery code ',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            TextSpan(text: 'to join '),
            TextSpan(
              text: '"Download app, get big prize" ',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            TextSpan(text: 'have a chance '),
            TextSpan(
              text: 'to win a smart tv ',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            TextSpan(text: 'worth nearly 1000\$.')
          ],
        ),
      ),
    },
    {
      "image": "assets/images/intro_2.png",
      "title": "Super convenient online pharmacy",
      "text": 'Full of great deals, free shipping from 13$. Accumulate Extracare points after every purchase.',
    },
    {
      "image": "assets/images/intro_3.png",
      "title": "Consult with a pharmacist online via video.",
      "text": 'Advice on prescriptions and drug use from a team of highly qualified pharmacists.'
    },
    {
      "image": "assets/images/intro_4.png",
      "title": "Look up drug information and disease symptoms",
      "text": 'Update the latest health information, look up information quickly and accurately.',
    },
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            'assets/images/intro_background.png',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            height: double.infinity,
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0.0, 8.0, 16.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 6,
                  child: PageView.builder(
                    onPageChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        currentPage = value;
                      });
                    },
                    itemCount: _introductionData.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => IntroductionContent(
                      image: _introductionData[index]['image'].toString(),
                      title: _introductionData[index]['title'].toString(),
                      text: _introductionData[index]['text'].toString(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        const Spacer(),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: List.generate(
                            _introductionData.length,
                            (index) => buildDot(index: index),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25)),
                        DefaultButton(
                          text: 'Continue',
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          textColor: kPrimaryColor,
                          press: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (BuildContext _context) =>
                                    const AcceptTermsScreen(),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  AnimatedContainer buildDot({int? index}) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: kAnimationDuration,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
      height: currentPage == index ? 6 : 4,
      width: currentPage == index ? 6 : 4,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: currentPage == index
            ? Colors.white
            : const Color(0x77FFFFFF),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

IntroductionContent code:

```
class IntroductionContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const IntroductionContent({
    Key? key,
    this.title,
    this.text,
    this.image,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String? title, text, image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Spacer(),
        const Spacer(),
        Image.asset(
          image!,
          height: 250,
        ),
        const Spacer(),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
          child: Text(
            title!,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 20,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
        Text(
          text!,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12,
            color: Colors.white,
            height: 1.5,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for help me fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your text type string to RichText and in your pageView, remove the `toString` from the `IntroductionContent` text parameter.

PageView.build

```
PageView.builder(
                    onPageChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        currentPage = value;
                      });
                    },
                    itemCount: _introductionData.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => IntroductionContent(
                      image: _introductionData[index]['image'].toString(),
                      title: _introductionData[index]['title'].toString(),
                      text: _introductionData[index]['text'], // here changed need
                    ),
                  ),
```

**IntroductionContent.class**

```
class IntroductionContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const IntroductionContent({
    Key key,
    this.title,
    this.text,
    this.image,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String title, image;
  final RichText text; // change text string to Richtext

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Spacer(),
        const Spacer(),
        Image.asset(
          image,
          height: 250,
        ),
        const Spacer(),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
          child: Text(
            title,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 20,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
        text, // here just assign your text
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Oh it's works but other normal text also change to RichText. Thanks a lot btw.